# receiving "invalid email address for recipient" when changing envelope status

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope created successfully with the following XML:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<status>created</status>
<emailSubject>DocuSign Notification</emailSubject>
<templateId>826882b3-63fd-4e3a-95c6-e9d901824xxx</templateId>
<templateRoles>
<templateRole>
<email>xxxxxxx@aol.com</email>
<name>Ed Test</name>
<roleName>Signer</roleName>
<routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
<clientUserId>25</clientUserId>
<tabs>...LEFT OUT FOR BREVITY...</tabs>
</templateRole></templateRoles></envelopeDefinition>
```

When I attempt to send the envelope with:

```
public string SendEnvelope(string envelopeID)
{
    string url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeID;
    string requestBody =
"<envelope>" +
"<status>sent</status>" +
"</envelope>";
    HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "PUT", requestBody, email, password);
    string response = getResponseBody(request);
    return response;
}
```

I receive:

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><errorCode>INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT</errorCode><message>The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows.</message></errorDetails>
```

There is nothing wrong with the email address.  If I create the envelope with status of "sent" instead of "created" it works fine.  I only get this error if attempting to change the envelope status.  Does anyone know why this occurs and how to work around it ?

Comment: As a next step to try and troubleshoot this, i would recommend turning on API logging and confirming the resulting API call and parameters match what you expect too: https://www.docusign.com/support/new/documentation/ndse-help/request-logging

Comment: I see that you are setting the `clientUserId` property in your envelope creation request, this means that recipient will be an embedded signer.  I'm wondering if that is related to the error you are seeing... when you make the PUT request to send the envelope I think you should be creating a signing token for your first recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ergin is correct.  If I change my process to add a few steps to retrieve the signers GUID that DocuSign creates, then it works.  It still seems like a bug, or at least an inconsistency, that the API handles it differently when created as "sent" versus created as "created" and immediately changed to "sent", but it at least has a workaround.  See my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661262/remove-templaterole-from-envelope) related post for my current, working process.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found a solution by changing my endpoint URL.

My requirement is to create a draft envelope and change the status to 'sent' at a later time. There were some optional signers that whenever missing, obviously, I was getting this error:

```
INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT
The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows.
```

I changed my endpoint to:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{account}}/envelopes?merge_roles_on_draft=true
```

AND it works just fine.

Read this in the API documentation [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) for more information:

[image: DocuSign Merge Roles on Draft]