# Remove templaterole from envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template with a Signer and a CarbonCopy role.  I create envelopes from the template.  Sometimes I don't have a CC email to use for the CC templaterole.  If I leave it blank, or if I don't provide the corresponding xml, (in both cases) I get an INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS error.  The role is not set to be required, so I don't understand why this error occurs.  Is there any way to remove the templaterole from the envelope to prevent this ?

Comment: Or, alternately, a way to add templateroles on the fly.  So I could have the template with only a signer role, create the envelope, then dynamically add CC roles as needed; is this possible ?

Comment: For Future Reference: I had the same issue and was able to fix it. Read my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764217/5405209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.  My resolution:

Have only the signer role in the template.

After the call to create envelope (status created), do a GET on recipients

Parse/capture/store the contents of the signers tag

Build xml for the entire recipients tag, inclusive of the contents of the signers tag and all the carbonCopy tags that you want

POST to recipients